# Parametros en archivo de Texto

Tags: c#

Estoy diseñando etiquetas por medio de Fingerprint, lo que necesito es modificar archivos de texto con parámetros, por ejemplo
`PP 18,060:PT "*%Value*"` donde value lo debo de sustituir por algun `string`, los archivos estarán guardado por número de parte `c:/Etiquetas/1234.txt`

```
     String allString = "";
        if (File.Exists(part))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(part))
            {
                allString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Al momento de abirir/leer todo el TXT querio solo modificar el campo de `"%*Value*"`
Si saben de alguna libreria  o algun modo de hacer esto , se los agradeceria.

Comment: .Net ya incluye lo que necesitas `String.Replace(string valorAntiguo, string valorNuevo)`

Comment: String.Replace(char old,char new), solo funciona con chars, no me permite strings

Comment: <https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx > documentación de String.Replace(string oldValue, string newValue), lo usas de la forma `allString.Replace(string cadenaRemplazar, string cadenaNueva)`

Answer (score 1):

```
allString = allString.Replace("*%Value*", "nuevo valor");
```

.Net ya incluye la función de `string.Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)` como anteriormente ya mencionaron